# .htaccess Non-'www' to 'www' Subdomain Redirection Only Works for Homepage

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like a WordPress site to redirect all URLs to the `www` subdomain. Using the `.htaccess` configuration below, the homepage is properly redirected (i.e. visiting `example.com/` redirects to `www.example.com/`) but internal pages aren't getting redirected (both `www.example.com/page` and `example.com/page` resolve and display the same content).

```
# Redirect non-www traffic to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Why aren't all URLs being redirected to the `www` subdomain?

Comment: What are your `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` settings in **Dashboard** > **"Settings"** > **"General"**?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you don't need to mess with .htaccess with a WordPress site.  Just set the General Settings -> "WordPress Address" and "Site Address" to the preferred version (www or non www) and WordPress takes care of the redirection for you.

Comment: the non www version still resolves and as I am working for a internet marketing company we need to make sure that search engines are not crawling both versions of the site so we don't get duplicate content.

Comment: Remove the .htaccess stuff and make sure those two general settings are set to the correct version of the site.

Comment: this edit does not fix the issue that I am having. Not to sound ungrateful I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what my issue was. In the .htaccess file the code for the www redirect was below the wordpress mod_rewrite.c and for some reason this was causing my problem.

Comment: That's why I said to remove it!!!!

Comment: Nemmy you said remove it you did not say change the it's position. I moved the rewrite above the wordpress mod. Your answer did not solve what my problem was...and I figured out how to solve my problem on my own so thanks for the effort I guess.

Comment: As I said, WordPress redirects perfectly without the need for messing around with .htaccess.  If yours isn't then your .htaccess has stuff in it that shouldn't be there.